# Fazer backup do banco mysql em PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, dump

Eu preciso de um botao de backup que eu consiga selecionar uma pasta onde vai salvar meus dados do mysql..
Eu encontrei alguns códigos de dump mysql porém todos com local de salvar definido via código e o que eu de fato preciso é que seja possivel escolher onde deve ser salvo.
Alguém me da uma luz de como eu implemento essa forma de salvar?

Answer (score 1):

1º - Vai salvar o arquivo na máquina do usuário ou no server?

Se for na máquina do usuário, experimente gerar o dump e fornecer o download para o cliente, removendo o dump após a conclusão do download.
[deleting a file after user download it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12668352/879613)

Desta forma, o usuário escolherá onde salvará o arquivo.
Se for do lado do server, pode experimentar o seguinte link.
[PHP File Browser](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/237790-php-file-browser/)

Comment: vou tentar amanha posto o resultado.. valeu